# Jboss - No Module Found Exception in sample kerberos project

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, kerberos, wildfly-12

1) I got the sample project tar file from the link: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToImplementKerberosAuthenticationWithASimpleRESTWebApp

Tar file : https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/52692-4-121670/kerberoes.tar.gz

I tried to build the project using **maven** and it is built successfully, It created a war: **kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**

2) I downloaded the wildfly from the link : https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/12.0.0.Final/wildfly-12.0.0.Final.zip

3) I copied the war to the /standalone/deployments/ folder and run the standalone.sh like below

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b $HOSTNAME
```

I get the following error,

```
2018-12-20 21:44:35,459 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/hariprashanth/Downloads/wild/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
2018-12-20 21:44:35,485 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/hariprashanth/Downloads/wild/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
2018-12-20 21:44:35,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2018-12-20 21:44:35,986 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
2018-12-20 21:44:36,149 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.2) 
2018-12-20 21:44:36,334 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0080: Valves are no longer supported, org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator is not activated.
2018-12-20 21:44:36,546 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1714)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1693)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1540)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.teiid.client
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1221)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1577)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1605)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:296)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:280)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 8 more

2018-12-20 21:44:36,555 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.teiid.client"}}
2018-12-20 21:44:36,578 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2018-12-20 21:44:36,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.module.service."deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

2018-12-20 21:44:36,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2018-12-20 21:44:36,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2018-12-20 21:44:36,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2018-12-20 21:44:36,684 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 12.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 4.0.0.Final) started (with errors) in 7558ms - Started 303 of 526 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 310 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

**Edited** :

```
After removing as suggested in the comment, I get the unsatisfied error,

2018-12-20 22:30:39,619 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.security.negotiation") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2018-12-20 22:30:40,435 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Bastille' 9.1.6.Final
2018-12-20 22:30:40,630 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2018-12-20 22:30:40,717 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.security.security-domain.\"EXAMPLE.COM\"",
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes",
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes]",
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes is missing [jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]",
        "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.\"EXAMPLE.COM\"]"
    ]
}
2018-12-20 22:30:40,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2018-12-20 22:30:40,740 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.security.security-domain."EXAMPLE.COM" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (unavailable) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./kerberoes] 

2018-12-20 22:30:40,855 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2018-12-20 22:30:40,861 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
```

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF of the war declares two dependencies, `org.jboss.teiid.client` and `org.jboss.teiid.common-core`. From a quick glance it seems like they aren't needed and you could just remove their declaration (or the whole MANIFEST.MF that becomes useless)

Comment: check the edited question please @Aaron

Comment: Good, I think you're one step closer :) The deployment is now missing the security domains, their creation is documented in the "HowToImplementKerberosAuthenticationWithASimpleRESTWebApp" article, I guess you missed that step?

Comment: A comment on the original article confirms my diagnostic of your original error btw : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToImplementKerberosAuthenticationWithASimpleRESTWebApp#comment-body-15508

Comment: @Aaron, Still I get the same error, I tried the changes you asked me to do

1) I added the content in standalone.xml as provided in the original link
2) Added the content in the web.xml and jboss-web.xml

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: added the standalone.xml in this edited question